# connectOutlet/disconnectOutlet with viewClass not working properly?

Tags: ember.js

I am connecting views to controller via method connectOutlet, but instead of regular parameters i am passing hash:

```
outletName: 'shaa',
viewClass: MyApp.ViewAView
```

It gets added correctly, but afterwards if i change that view by calling:

```
MyApp.router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({
    outletName: 'shaa',
    viewClass: MyApp.ViewBView
});
```

Ember does not replace old view with new one. I have this fiddle to ilustrate my point
http://jsfiddle.net/6p6XJ/48/

I thought, that maybe disconnecting it manually by calling `disconnectOutlet` will work, but no http://jsfiddle.net/6p6XJ/50/ . BTW in this fiddle i checked if outlet can be connected outside `Route`'s `connectOutlets` method.
Can views, that are connected via atribute hash be disconnected somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's working properly, though in your examples, the connect/disconnect stuff have to be executed in a runloop, using Ember.run. Here I use Ember.run.later in order to defer.

```
Ember.run.later(function(){
  MyApp.router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({
    outletName: 'shaa',
    viewClass: MyApp.ViewBView
  });
  Ember.run.later(function(){ 
    MyApp.router.get('applicationController').disconnectOutlet('shaa');
  },1000);

 },1000);​
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/6p6XJ/53/

Comment: Why is that? does not say so in docs. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Usually you use these fonction inside the run loop (it's implicit, you don't have to take care of this), by handling event in the router (or in view or controller). see http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/6p6XJ/54/